# Shortest paths in graph with labeled edges

Tags: python, graph, networkx, graph-algorithm, shortest-path

### Problem

Suppose I have a graph with labeled nodes and edges (see figure). My goal is to get the *set* of all shortest paths between A and D.

[image]

### What I have so far

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge('A', 'B')
G.add_edge('B', 'D')
G.add_edge('B', 'C')

shortest_path = nx.shortest_path(G, 'A', 'D')
```

In `shortest_path` I get `['A', 'B', 'D']`. Of course, this *is* the shortest path represented through the nodes, but what I need is to:

1) add edge labels in my graph

2) find the *set* of all possible shortest paths. Ideally, in `shortest_paths` I would want to have an output as follows:
 `[ A -> a -> B, B -> b -> D], [A -> a -> B, B -> c -> D]`

### Questions

1) Is this possible to be done with networkx?

2) If not, what other graph libraries contain functions which solve problems with such scenario (doesn't have to be Python)?

Comment: For duplicate edges you need to use nx.MultiGraph instead. Networks does support arbitrary attributes for edges G.add_edge("A", "B", name="c"). To get the output in a custom format though you'll have to write some code yourself. For your paeticular case it shouldn't be more than half a dosen lines though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert your edges to nodes and use the function `all_shortest_paths()`:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.MultiGraph()
G.add_edge('A', 'B', label='a')
G.add_edge('B', 'D', label='b')
G.add_edge('B', 'D', label='c')
G.add_edge('B', 'C', label='d')
G.add_edge('C', 'D', label='e')

# Convert edges to nodes
g = nx.Graph()
for i, j, label in G.edges(data='label'):
    g.add_edge(i, label)
    g.add_edge(j, label)

print(list(nx.all_shortest_paths(g, 'A', 'D')))
# [['A', 'a', 'B', 'b', 'D'], ['A', 'a', 'B', 'c', 'D']]
```